# Can I use Apex and SOQL to import data from other objects into a new custom object?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, visual-workflow, parent-to-child

This is my first time posting in stack exchange :) I have a Salesforce Admin Cert, but I have very little experience in the realm of writing code. So here goes.

The goal of my apex code is to import data from other Salesforce objects into a new custom object. Ultimately, I want to use the new custom object as a place to store data for the "Get Records" portion of the Flow builder. Eventually, I plan to access a large amount of internal and external data and I don't want the flow process to timeout. I'm only building the bare bones to get started then I wanted to expand on it. It's proving difficult.

I wrote a parent to child relationship SOQL query in the beginning of the method. Then an iteration for loop to cycle through the gathered data and attribute it to a specific field in the new custom object that I already created. I have the parent object which is simple enough to reference in the iteration for loop but once I try to reference the child objects I get various syntax errors or "variable does not exist" errors.

```
public class NewNARCFlow {
    public static void GatherInfo() {
        List<Proposal_Products__c> products = [
            SELECT Id, Proposal__c, StartDateTime__c, EndDateTime__c, (
                SELECT Id, Child_Products_From_Package__c, StartDateTime__c, EndDateTime__c
                FROM Child_Products_From_Package__r pc
                WHERE (EndDateTime__c >= TODAY)
            ), (
                SELECT ProposalProduct__c, PackageChild__c, Proposal_ID__c, Status__c, Type__c
                FROM PFX_Approval_Processes__r ap
                WHERE Type__c = 'Ad Operations' AND Status__c IN ('Not Requested', 'Change Pending')
            )
            FROM Proposal_Products__c
            WHERE EndDateTime__c >= TODAY
        ];
        
       New_NARC_Flow_Data__c[] newNarcs = new New_NARC_Flow_Data__c[]{};
            
        for (Proposal_Products__c pp : products) {
            New_NARC_Flow_Data__c newNarc = new New_NARC_Flow_Data__c();
                newNarc.Product_Id__c = pp.Id;
                newNarc.Proposal_ID__c = pp.Proposal__c;
                newNarc.Product_StartDateTime__c = pp.StartDateTime__c;
                newNarc.Product_EndDateTime__c = pp.EndDateTime__c;

 //Product_Id__c, Proposal_ID__c, Product_StartDateTime__c, Product_EndDateTime__c are fields in new custom object
System.debug(products);
                  
            
            newNarcs.add(newNarc);
        }
            

    insert newNarcs;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Good first question you've got yourself here. Could you [edit] your question to include the attempts you've made to access the child records and the exact text of the error message(s) you're getting? The child records are just a `List<SObject>` embedded inside of the parent record, but there are a few things that could be going wrong. Seeing the error(s) and your attempt(s) usually helps in getting more accurate and tailored answers.

Comment: Good to know! :) . A developer colleague took a look at my code and suggested doing nested loops. Do you know of a good resource that I could reference for nested loops?